# "Decoding error, image format unsupported" in Microsoft Face API

Tags: java, api, face

I'm trying to use Microsoft Face API. For that I have the following code that was given by Microsoft as a sample (at the end of this page https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236):

```
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

try {
    URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://api.projectoxford.ai/face/v1.0/detect");

    builder.setParameter("returnFaceId", "false");
    builder.setParameter("returnFaceLandmarks", "false");
    builder.setParameter("returnFaceAttributes", "age,gender");

    URI uri = builder.build();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
    request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "...");

    String body = Base64.encodeBase64String(img);

    StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity(body);
    request.setEntity(reqEntity);

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    if (entity != null) {
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
            return JsonParser.parse(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
    }
} catch (URISyntaxException | IOException | ParseException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

return null;
```

but I get the following error:

```
{"error":{"code":"InvalidImage","message":"Decoding error, image format unsupported."}}
```

The image that I am using for tests is this one:
http://www.huntresearchgroup.org.uk/images/group/group_photo_2010.jpg
(found it on the internet in a quick search)

It respect all the requisits set by Microsoft, size and format... If I use it in the site it works https://www.projectoxford.ai/demo/face#detection

The `String body` from the convertion of my array of bytes to a string in base64 is also ok, I test it in this website: http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

The error message it's quite simple, but I fail to see where I am worng. Anyone might know whats the problem?

**UPDATE**

The variable `img`:

```
img = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(imgPath));
```

Comment: The `img` you are encoding. All good with that? I see you are using the Apache Commons Base64. A small FYI, Java 1.8 has [[Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html)].

Comment: Didnt know that, I change the code to use Java Base64, I got the same problem.

Comment: I was asking you about the variable `img`. You haven't included any information about that.

Comment: If I Base64 decode an incorrect string and send it, it obviously won't work. That is what my concern was. Are you initializing `img` properly?

Comment: yes, my bad, I updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to discover the problem... Instead of:

```
String body = Base64.encodeBase64String(img);
StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity(body);
request.setEntity(reqEntity);
```

I needed to do:

```
ByteArrayEntity reqEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(img, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
request.setEntity(reqEntity);
```

I think that the Documentation is outdated...

Answer (score 1):

I made the following change. Instead of sending an encoded image, I am sending the URL for the image.

```
request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{YOUR_FACES_API_KEY}");

StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity("{ \"url\":\"http://www.huntresearchgroup.org.uk/images/group/group_photo_2010.jpg\" }");
request.setEntity(reqEntity);
```

This gets the response:

```
[{"faceRectangle":{"top":878,"left":2718,"width":312,"height":312},"faceAttributes":{"gender":"male","age":28.5}},{"faceRectangle":{"top":593,"left":573,"width":310,"height":310},"faceAttributes":{"gender":"male","age":27.5}},{"faceRectangle":{"top":1122,"left":1014,"width":294,"height":294},"faceAttributes":{"gender":"female","age":27.7}},{"faceRectangle":{"top":915,"left":1773,"width":277,"height":277},"faceAttributes":{"gender":"female","age":36.7}},{"faceRectangle":{"top":566,"left":1276,"width":269,"height":269},"faceAttributes":{"gender":"male","age":40.7}},{"faceRectangle":{"top":677,"left":2134,"width":257,"height":257},"faceAttributes":{"gender":"female","age":35.2}}]
```

Will work on sending an encoded image soon. Will update this post accordingly.

EDIT:

Downloading image from URL

```
String base64Img = null;
byte[] bytes = null;
String imgBinaryString = null;
String base64ImgBinaryString = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.businessstudynotes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Role-of-Group.jpg");
    //"http://www.huntresearchgroup.org.uk/images/group/group_photo_2010.jpg");
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);
    bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte by: bytes)
        sb.append(Integer.toBinaryString(by & 0xFF));
    imgBinaryString = sb.toString();

    base64Img = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
    byte[] base64Bytes = base64Img.getBytes("UTF-8");
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte by: base64Bytes) {
        sb.append(Integer.toBinaryString(by & 0xFF));
    }
    base64ImgBinaryString = sb.toString();

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.out.println("Download issue");
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.out.println("ImageIO issue");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`imgBinaryString` contains a binary representation of the image; `base64ImgBinaryString` contains a binary representation of the Base 64 representation of the image.

To upload this image...

```
URI uri = builder.build(); // builder = new URIBuilder("https://api.projectoxford.ai/face/v1.0/detect");
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{YOUR_FACES_API_KEY");

StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity(base64ImgBinaryString);
request.setEntity(reqEntity);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
```

Setting the `StringEntity` to both `imgBinaryString` and `base64ImgBinaryString` results in the same response...

`{"error":{"code":"InvalidImage","message":"Decoding error, image format unsupported."}}`

***Now, the good stuff. This works...***

```
ByteArrayEntity reqEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(bytes, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
request.setEntity(reqEntity);
```

where `bytes` is the byte-array for the image; but a Base64 representation of this doesn't work. Someone **really** needs to update the documentation.

Comment: Yes, with the url is working fine, the problem is with the encoded image. It is the first time that I am working with encoded images, so after some time trying to figure it out, I decided to ask for help. Will wait for your update, ty.

Comment: I have been trying to use binary data with this tool: https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236/console
But I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @lulas Yep! it's amazing how nothing works, and the spec itself is not clear at all about how what format they accept binary data in. I have asked someone I know at Microsoft to find something out about this problem. Let's see how that goes.

Comment: @lulas Working. At last. :)

Comment: @lulas I just noticed that you had also added an answer haha

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [CognitiveJ](http://github.com/CognitiveJ/cognitivej), an open source library that will handle the communications & interactions with the MS faces API. If you don't want to use the library then you can have a look at the code to see what the REST API expects.

(disclosure - I'm the author of the library).

Answer (score 0):

```
import okhttp3.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            doRequest();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public static void doRequest() throws IOException {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"),
                new File(".//src//main//java//Archivo_001.png"));

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false&returnFaceAttributes=age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise")
                .post(body)
                .addHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "1d88f949af3443ea8cc16b7146bd7501")
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        System.out.println(response.body().string());

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that this answer would be helpful to someone in the future, since I struggled with this quite a bit before finding this thread and realising the issue was on the documentation.

I managed to get the octet-stream type request working with HttpClient and RestTemplate.

1. HttpClient version:

   ```
   HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
   try
   {
       URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder(String.format("https://%s.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect", region));

       List<String> faceAttributes = Arrays.asList("age","gender","headPose","smile","facialHair","glasses","emotion","hair","makeup","occlusion","accessories","blur","exposure","noise");
       String faceAttributesCommaSeparated = String.join(",", faceAttributes);
       builder.setParameter("returnFaceId", "true");
       builder.setParameter("returnFaceLandmarks", "false");
       builder.setParameter("returnFaceAttributes", faceAttributesCommaSeparated);

       URI uri = builder.build();
       HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
       request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
       request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

       ByteArrayEntity reqEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(fileContentBytes, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
       request.setEntity(reqEntity);

       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
       HttpEntity entity = (HttpEntity) response.getEntity();

   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   }
   ```
2. RestTemplate:

   ```
   private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
   HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
   headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
   headers.add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

   List<String> faceAttributes = Arrays.asList("age","gender","headPose","smile","facialHair","glasses","emotion","hair","makeup","occlusion","accessories","blur","exposure","noise");
   String faceAttributesCommaSeparated = String.join(",", faceAttributes);

   MultiValueMap<String, String> paramsMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
   paramsMap.add("returnFaceId", "true");
   paramsMap.add("returnFaceLandmarks", "false");
   paramsMap.add("returnFaceAttributes", faceAttributesCommaSeparated);

   HttpEntity<byte[]> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(fileContentBytes, headers);
   ResponseEntity<String> response = null;
   try {
       response = restTemplate.exchange(
               String.format("%s/face/v1.0/detect", endpoint),
               HttpMethod.POST,
               requestEntity,
               String.class,
               paramsMap
       );
   } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

I left some specific values as variables but the gist of it should be clear. I will be using the restTemplate version in production code with a few minor changes.